# Diode voltage drop homework

Tags: diodes

Design the circuit of Fig. E4.15 so that V<sub>O</sub> = 3 V when I<sub>L</sub> = 0, and V<sub>O</sub> changes by 40 mV per 1 mA of I<sub>L</sub> change. Find R assuming that diodes available have 0.7 V drop in I = 1 mA.

I found I=Is exp(v/nVT), I put the values here and find Is, assuming n=1.

Then I find I=Is exp(0.75/0.025)=...

So R=(15-3)/I=...

Why do I need the change in V<sub>O</sub> per 1mA of I<sub>L</sub> change?

[image]

Comment: That's not the way it works, David. This is obviously homework but it shows no attempt at a solution. Please edit showing your work or it will be closed pretty quickly.

Comment: "*just guide me what should I do*. Edit and type in what you *do* understand.

Comment: _”Why do I need the change in V0 per 1mA of IL change?”_ Because whoever designed the question wanted you to think about the downside or usable range for a zener (or diode like this) regulator. Or just throw you a curveball.

Comment: @David - Please don't remove all the original text from the question, after you've received an answer. That is not how things are done here, so I have done a "rollback" to the previous version of the question. Thanks.

Comment: David, as you have found, this site is quite useful but you seem to be struggling with how it works - and I too have no idea why you deleted the question after a couple of us had gone to the trouble of helping you. Perhaps the [Tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) might be of help.

Comment: Rolled back again. Once this question is posted here and answered, it does not belong to you any more. People put their time to read it, comment on it and answer it. They got reputation reward for it. Please respect it.

Comment: David, please stop vandalising the site. You posted a question and we answered it. You accepted my answer and then unaccepted it, removed the image from the question thereby making it of no use. What's the problem?

Comment: Please don't edit as anonymous user as well.

Answer (score 2):

- Work out what the voltage drop across the diodes would be at 1 mA.
- Now work out how much more you would need to increase the current to get 3 V across the diodes.
- Now what voltage is across the resistor? What is the current through it? What is the value of R?